# Can an Android wearable be paired without using the Android Wear app?

Tags: wear-os

I am working on a phone which contains a modified AOSP and would like to pair it with a watch.

As the phone is based on AOSP it does not contain Google Play Services, and therefore it is not possible to connect to Google Play and download/install the Android Wear App.

Is there any way I can pair the watch with the phone without using the Android Wear app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension of gruszczy answer, which now is deleted. He wrote that it is not possible.

Android Wear needs Google Play Services to work, so you would need to implement them on your AOSP project, however they are not open sourced.
However you can create a Bluetooth connection to it and create own Android Wear app that will receive you commands and data as it would do by Google Play Services - and react to them (for example make notifications and synchronise them between phone and Wear device).

So yes, it is possible but quite hard, also it look like it would work with iOS devices if somebody would wrote app for that.

Also one problem that remains is that on Android Wear first start it requires syncing by Google Play Services to phone before using it. And for now I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: I've been wondering if its possible to install GPS - the .apks are easily findable on the internet, but when I install them I get errors about GPS stopping.

Comment: I don't see how it is connected to previous question.
Also if my answer solves your question please mark it as approved.

Comment: Yeah, right. But if you think that there are people who want to help and look for questions without answer... why make their life harder?